# linear differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system of linear differential equations:

$$\begin{split}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=−3x+y\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&￼=x−3y
\end{split}$$

1. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors associated with the system.
2. Find the equilibrium and determine its stability.
3. Draw the $x$- and $y$-nullclines in the phase plane.
4. Sketch the solution curve for the initial value $x(0)=6$ , $y(0)=2$ in the phase plane.

Comment: What are your thoughts about how to approach this problem? Please write some form of an attempt to solve it, and we will be glad to comment and give more hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: Please fill in the details.

Consider the following system of linear differential equations:

$$\begin{split}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= −3x+y \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &￼= x−3y
\end{split}$$

$$x(0) = 6, y(0) = 2$$

Our system can be written as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x'(t) \\ y'(t)\end{bmatrix} = A x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ 1 & -3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)\end{bmatrix}$$

For the eigenvalues, we find $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, and for the eigenvectors, we solve $[A - \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$. This leads to:

$$\lambda_1 = -4, v_1 = (-1,1), ~ \lambda_2 = -2, v_2 = (1,1)$$

From this, we can write the solution as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)\end{bmatrix} = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2$$

We also have the initial condition, $\begin{bmatrix} x(0) \\ y(0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} $, so we can find the closed-form solution as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 e^{-4 t} \left(2 e^{2 t}+1\right) \\ 2 e^{-4 t} \left(2 e^{2 t}-1\right)\end{bmatrix}$$

There is a single equilibrium at $(x, y) = (0,0)$. What does the solution or the eigenvalues tell you about its stability (as well as the phase portrait)?

A phase portrait, with nullclines and the two initial points is:

[image]

Comment: What do you use to make those phase portraits ?

Comment: Its very helpful, thank you

Comment: λ1 = -4 and λ2 = −2 ,

Answer (score 0):

You should try yourself first. Here is a first hint to get you started. Let
$$\vec{z} = \pmatrix{x\\y} \quad \text{ and } \quad A = \pmatrix{-3 & 1 \\ 1 & -3}$$
then your system looks like $\vec{z}' = Az$.

Now diagonalize $A$.

Comment: -1 should be -3 in matrix A

Comment: @jesse fixed type